# Check for values found in one Excel range, but not another

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a two named ranges, user input `Profiles` (vertical range of one column) and pre-determined `ProfileNames` (horizontal range of one row). I have a data validation step in my tool, and would like to check if any values input to `Profiles` are *not* found in `ProfileNames`. I'm trying to find out a way to do this in one formula but I seemed to be stumped.

Currently, this is achieved like this: each cell in `ProfileNames` is its own Name (`Profile1`, `Profile2`, etc.). Then this formula is used:

`COUNTIFS(Profiles,"<>"&Profile1,
          Profiles,"<>"&Profile2,
          ...)`

with anything greater than 0 triggering a popup. I'd like to move past this, as there will eventually be 200+ profiles to check and this formula is unwieldy. I need a formula to replace the above one which will detect any cells in `Profiles` that do not match at least one cell in `ProfileNames`.

Sample data:

`Cooling | Heating | Cooking 
1         .5       .75`

The first row above (Cooling:Cooking) is `ProfileNames` "Cooling" is `Profile1`, Heating is `Profile2`, etc.
This column is `Profiles`:

`Cooling
 Cooling
 Cooking
 Heating
 Heating`

I'm looking to avoid using `Profile1` etc as there will be 200+ of these and the formula being used now may expand to exceed maximum character limits.

Comment: Could you please some sample data and describe exactly how do you work? It's not clear now.

Comment: @MátéJuhász edited to add sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula to check. Type

```
=SUM((Profiles = ProfileNames) * 1)
```

into a cell, but instead of using enter press control-shift-enter. The result is the number of entries in `Profiles` that match an entry in `ProfileNames`. Therefore, you know that if there are e.g. 5 entries in `Profiles` and the sum is 5, all are included in `ProfileNames`. If the sum is less than 5, one of the entries in `Profiles` isn't correct.

Explanation: `Profiles = ProfileNames` creates a matrix of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s corresponding to checking each row in `Profiles` against each column in `ProfileNames`. The `* 1` turns that matrix into a matrix of numbers, and `SUM` sums them up.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid using an array formula but it seems to be the only way. I ended up scrapping this part of the tool anyway.